# How to wired Raspberry Pi Zero with Nokia 5110?

Tags: pi-zero

I want to use this library https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_PCD8544 with Raspberry Pi Zero and Nokia 5110 LCD

Here is my interpretation based on the article https://learn.adafruit.com/nokia-5110-3310-monochrome-lcd/python-wiring

[image]

Can I ask someone to check  ? Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

It seems okay.

The only obvious omission is there is no connection from GPIO 13 to LCD LED.  Presumably that is not needed for your set up.

Comment: If you mean LCD backlight I don't need it.
I don't know why, but sample from example https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_PCD8544/tree/master/examples doesn't work in my case. SPI was enabled via rasp-config, dependency was installed.